# Summarize a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I have a Requirement I want the following result set :

```
Type       Receipts Issues Balance
==================================
Purchase    10       0     10
Purchase    5        0     15
Sales       0        2     13  
Purchase    10       0     23
Sales       0        5     18
```

where the last column sholud be summarize Balance=(Receipts-Issues)+Balance

My query is :

```
SELECT type, 
       Isnull(receipts, 0)                         AS Receipts, 
       Isnull(issues, 0)                           AS Issues, 
       ( Isnull(receipts, 0) - Isnull(issues, 0) ) AS Balance 
FROM   (SELECT 'Purchasse' AS Type, 
               PBD.qty     AS Receipts, 
               NULL        AS Issues 
        FROM   tbl_purchasebillmain PB 
               JOIN tbl_purchasebilldetail PBD 
                 ON PBD.purchasebill_id = PB.record_id 
               JOIN tbl_product_master PM 
                 ON PM.record_id = PBD.product_id 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Purchasse Return' AS Type, 
               NULL               AS Receipts, 
               PRD.qty            AS Issues 
        FROM   dbo.tbl_purchasereturnmain PR 
               JOIN dbo.tbl_purchasereturndetail PRD 
                 ON PRD.purchasereturnbill_id = PR.record_id 
               JOIN tbl_purchasebilldetail PBD 
                 ON PBD.record_id = PRD.purchasebilldetail_id 
               JOIN tbl_product_master PM 
                 ON PM.record_id = PBD.product_id) AS s
```

Comment: Doyou get an error or do you simply not get the result you want?

Comment: It would be interesting to have an auto-increment id on this table so, you can take the balance from current id fetched-1 in a sub-query. Don't know if it's that you want else, nevermind :)

Comment: @Jakob , I dont get the results I expect

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you mean by (receipts-issues)+balance, but i assume you want this:

```
SELECT type, 
       sum(Isnull(receipts, 0))                         AS Receipts, 
       sum(Isnull(issues, 0))                           AS Issues, 
       sum(( Isnull(receipts, 0) - Isnull(issues, 0) )) AS Balance 
FROM   (SELECT 'Purchasse' AS Type, 
               PBD.qty     AS Receipts, 
               NULL        AS Issues 
        FROM   tbl_purchasebillmain PB 
               JOIN tbl_purchasebilldetail PBD 
                 ON PBD.purchasebill_id = PB.record_id 
               JOIN tbl_product_master PM 
                 ON PM.record_id = PBD.product_id 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Purchasse Return' AS Type, 
               NULL               AS Receipts, 
               PRD.qty            AS Issues 
        FROM   dbo.tbl_purchasereturnmain PR 
               JOIN dbo.tbl_purchasereturndetail PRD 
                 ON PRD.purchasereturnbill_id = PR.record_id 
               JOIN tbl_purchasebilldetail PBD 
                 ON PBD.record_id = PRD.purchasebilldetail_id 
               JOIN tbl_product_master PM 
                 ON PM.record_id = PBD.product_id) AS s 
group by type
```